# How to render nested hash values in rails as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**NOTE**

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
```

`user` is an activerecord instance, hence `user.as_json` is to be called before chain calling any hash methods (ex: `#except`/`delete`) on `user`.

Instead of using `dig`, I did -

```
render json: user.as_json.except('prof_pic_path').merge('prof_pic_path' => user.prof_pic_path.url)
```

**UPDATE**

Tried this from following suggestions on which I am getting error- `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):`

```
def show
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user[:url] = user.delete('prof_pic_path')[:url]
  render json: user
end
```

**OLD ASK**

Actually, I am trying to **extract a nested hash value** and render as json with little reformatting [optional]. My hash looks like this:

```
{
    "user_id": "emusk",
    "f_name": "Elon",
    "l_name": "Musk",
    "picture": {
        "url": "https://yo-de"
    },
    "distance": 0.53
}
```

I am trying to achieve as this:

```
{
    "user_id": "emusk",
    "f_name": "Elon",
    "l_name": "Musk",
    "picture_url": "https://yo-de",
    "distance": 0.53
}
```

Tried few ways, could not reach anywhere closer. 
Any helpful insight much appreciated!

Comment: How did you obtain the nested hash? Maybe you can create what you need to begin with and skip a step.

Comment: nested hash is generated in the model, using `gem carrierwave` uploader, and I am calling- `render json: user` in the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is dealing with two distinctly different cases, so I will take them in turn.

### Changing a hash

First, remove the key you don't want with [`Hash#except`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except):

```
hash = {
  "user_id": "emusk",
  "f_name": "Elon",
  "l_name": "Musk",
  "picture": {
    "url": "https://yo-de"
  },
  "distance": 0.53
}

hash.except('picture')
```

Get the nested value you need with [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) or [`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) (Ruby 2.3):

```
hash.fetch('picture', {})['url']
hash.dig('picture', 'url')
```

Finally, put this together:

```
hash.except('picture').merge('picture_url' => hash.dig('picture', 'url'))
hash.except('picture').merge('picture_url' => hash.fetch('picture', {})['url'])
```

### Serializing an ActiveRecord model

You said that `picture` is being added by carrierwave, so absent clarification I am assuming that you can get the url by calling `user.picture.url`.

First, create a `picture_url` helper on `User`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ... etc

  delegate :url, to: :picture, prefix: true
end
```

Next, tell [Rails' JSON serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) to include its output.

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
render json: user.as_json(methods: :picture_url)
```

Comment: Well explained @Adam. I am trying your first approach first, `user = User.first.as_json` and `user.dig` inside `merge` gives me `NoMethodError (undefined method `dig' for #<Hash:0x0000000c05b250>)`

Comment: Also from console while querying user object, it returns `<User id: 2, picture: "Jimmy.jpg">` which is different to the format `render :json` as it does not contain `url`, can it be a reason for `NoMethodError`, Mainly I don't want to create another column `picture_url` instead reformat the hash

Comment: @Ranjan `dig` only works on hashes and arrays, but if you are converting a `User` instance to JSON it's better to just create the hash you want in the first place. Adding a `picture_url` method like I do above does not create a new column in the database, it merely forwards method calls elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First, delete that key-value pair with nested hash:

```
removed_item = hash.delete('picture') # => {:url=>"https://yo-de"}
```

After that, merge new key-value pair into your hash and convert it to json:

```
hash.merge!(picture_url: removed_item[:url]).to_json
```

Comment: `render :json  removed_item` gives me `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):`

Comment: Ranjan, I believe you're supposed to render the `hash`. `removed_item` is just @iskvmk's temporary variable.

Comment: rendering hash is giving me an error, so I though to check the remove_item by rendering it also, Updated the question with your answer and @iskvmk's

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
hash[:picture_url] = hash.delete(:picture)[:url]
hash.to_json
```